# problem with eigenvalues and eigenvectors_2

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an endomorphism $F:R^3 \rightarrow R^3 $ such that $ker F=  \left \{ (x,y,z)| x-y+2z=0 \right \}$ and $v=(1,0,1)$ is an eigenvector for $ \lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}$
It is asked to find the matrix of the endomorphism in the base $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$

I can find a basis of $ker F=<(1,1,0),(-2,0,1)>$
I know that ker F is the eigenspace relating to the eigenvalue $ \lambda _0=0$.
Then I can take the eigenvector $v=(1,0,1)$ related to the eigenvalue $ \lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.
So a base of $R^3$ is $B=\left \{ (1,0,1),(1,1,0),(-2,0,1) \right \}$

$F(1,0,1)=\frac{1}{2}(1,0,1)=(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$

$F(1,1,0)=(0,0,0)$

$F(-2,0,1)=(0,0,0)$

Now I can all the elements for the matrix $A_B=\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0  \end{Bmatrix}$

Now I have to find the matrices to change the coordinate from the base $e$ to $ B$ and from $B$ to $e$

$(1,0,0)= \frac{1}{3}*(1,0,1)+ 0*(1,1,0)+\frac{1}{3}*(-2,0,1)$
$(0,1,0)= -\frac{1}{3}*(1,0,1)+ 1*(1,1,0)+\frac{1}{3}*(-2,0,1)$
$(0,0,1)= \frac{2}{3}*(1,0,1)+ 0*(1,1,0)+\frac{1}{3}*(-2,0,1)$

$M_{Be}=\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\-\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}   \end{Bmatrix}$

And the inverse
$M_{eB}=\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1   \end{Bmatrix}$

$M_{eB}*A_B*M_{Be}=\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1   \end{Bmatrix}*\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0  \end{Bmatrix}*\begin{Bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\-\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}   \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}   \end{Bmatrix}$

is it right or am i making mistakes?

Comment: What is an *autospace*?

Comment: @Bernard Does eigenspace make sense?

Comment: @Anne: Yes. I've never heard of ‘autospace’.

Comment: Bug in the title...

Comment: If I understand well, $A_{\mathcal B}$  is the matrix of $F$ in the basis of eigenvectors. So it should be the diagonal matrix with (in this order) $1/2, 0,0$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, indeed. But why $F(1,0,1)=\frac{1}{2}(1,0,1)=(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$?    The three vectors are surely a base and this should sufficient to have the matrix (every column is the F(v) where v is the vector of the base)

Comment: You wrote $(1,0,1)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda_1$!

Comment: @Bernard Yes, $\lambda_1=1/2$. 1 is only to differentiate from $\lambda_0$

Comment: That's why $F(1,0,1)=\frac12(1,0,1)$. It's the definition of an eigenvector.

Comment: @Bernard ok, I agree with you

Comment: @Bernard So in your opinion is $A_B$ wrong?

Comment: Yes: in a basis of eigenvector, the matrix is a diagonal matrix, by definition of an eigenvector.

Comment: @Bernard what do you think about the last part of the exercise?

Comment: The end is fine. The only error was on the matrix of $F$ in the basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: The columns of $A_B$ are indeed the images of the basis vectors that you found, but they have to be expressed relative to the basis $B$, not relative to the standard basis, as you’ve done. In that basis, $v=(1,0,0)$ and its image under $A$ is $(1/2,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a shortcut. The equation of the kernel tells you that $A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ x+2z \\ z \end{pmatrix} = 0$. The eigenvalue equation tells you that $A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Taking $x = z = 1$ gives you $0 = A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + 3 A e_2$, whence $A e_2 = - \dfrac 1 6 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = - \dfrac 1 6 e_1 - \dfrac 1 6 e_3$.

Taking now $x=0$ and $z=1$ gives $0 = A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 A e_2 + A e_3 = - \dfrac 1 3 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + A e_3$, whence $A e_3 = \dfrac 1 3 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac 1 3 e_1 + \dfrac 1 3 e_3$.

Taking $x=1$ and $z=0$ gives $0 = A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = A e_1 + A e_2$, whence $A e_1 = \dfrac 1 6 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac 1 6 e_1 + \dfrac 1 6 e_3$.

It follows that $A = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac 1 6 & - \dfrac 1 6 & \dfrac 1 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \dfrac 1 6 & - \dfrac 1 6 & \dfrac 1 3 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac 1 6 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.